# Adding jquery mask to input, removing 0 as default

Tags: jquery, input

I wanted to use https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ on my input, so I can define my mask so It always has two zeros on the start of the input. Somehow the plugin recognizes 0 as something else...

For example I want to have 00 on the start of my input, so the user can add the rest of his phone, "00 49 355-559", and the mask is "0000-000-000", if I wanted to have two two's the mask as "2200-000-000" would always put 22 at the beggining. So how can I set zeros on the start?

I've tried with jquery like this, but only works properly with paste event so far, since I don't want the value to be there initially, only when the user start typing or pasting the values on input...

```
$('#myInput').mask("0000-000-000");
$('#myInput').on("paste", function () {
        $(this).val("000-0");
    });
```

Comment: You could amend the functionality of the `0` character in the mask so that it's not a wildcard for any digit. See the [docs](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#global-options)., specifically `translation`. I'd suggest changing it to `d`, then the pattern would be `00 dd ddd-ddd`

Comment: changing mask to "00dd-ddd-ddd" gets me "digit digit dd-ddd-ddd", or should I use the translation on my .js file so I can alter the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

use available options like **onKeyPress**, **onChange**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var options = {
     onComplete: function(cep, event, currentField) {
       console.log('OK CEP Completed!:' + cep);
       var prefix = "00";
       var val = cep;
       if (val.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) {
         event.target.value = prefix + val;
       }
    },
    onKeyPress: function(cep, event, currentField, options) {
      console.log('OK A key was pressed!:', cep, ' event: ', event,
        'currentField: ', currentField, ' options: ', options);
       var prefix = "00";
       var val = event.target.value;
       if (val.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) {
         event.target.value = prefix + val;
       }    
    },
    onChange: function(cep, event) {
      console.log('OK cep changed! ', cep);
      var prefix = "00"
      if (cep.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) {
        event.target.value = prefix + cep;
      }
    },
    onInvalid: function(val, e, f, invalid, options) {
      var error = invalid[0];
      console.log("Digit: ", error.v, " is invalid for the position: ", error.p, ". We expect something like: ", error.e);
    }
  };


  $('#text').mask('0000-000-000', options);

});
```

Comment: this is great, but deleting it on backspace seems to be broken

Comment: you can check condition for **delete or backspace** in on `KeyPress` method. like     `var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;`